# Question title cut off on bottom in review on specific sites

Tags: bug, review, design

[image: !]

As you can see here, in Arqade's review page, the lower parts of the letters `p` and `g` in the title got cut off.

The review can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/116517).

Although this review is already finished, the bug still exists in an unfinished one.

I am using Safari 8.0.1 (latest version) on OS X Mavericks, 100% zoom. After testing, the bug exists even with different zooms. This bug exists on the mobile site too. Chrome also repros this bug.

This is also happening on [a review on TeX-LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4586/5764). Thanks Werner!

This is probably caused by the fact that style is added to the h1 as inline style `(margin-bottom: 15px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;)`. Thanks bjb568!

Is it possible to fix this bug?

Comment: Edited. Added link.

Comment: I think this belongs on the site meta, since it is a site specific layout issue.

Comment: I don't know if this also happens on other sites, so I decided to put it here. If this is exclusive to Arqade, I will move it.

Comment: No repro for me on IE11 and Chrome on Windows 7/x64

Comment: What browser? What OS? Are you zoomed in/out?

Comment: But that might be due to the fact that I'm looking at a finished review...

Comment: This is also visible on [tex.se]: [Post title font cut off under review queue](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4586/5764)

Comment: OS X Mavericks, Safari, 100% zoom. @Werner may I add that to my question?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493: Sure, since it has to be fixed.

Comment: Comments do not bump anything. You can ping @Oded though and let him know you added the info he asked.

Comment: @Oded Ping ping pingy ping.

Comment: What version of safari? Are you using the latest?

Comment: 8.0.2, added into question.

Comment: @Oded 8.0.2 and see above comment

Comment: I don't have the hardware to reproduce this - looking for someone on the team that can.

Comment: This is still a problem on [tex.se] under Google Chrome 41.0.2272.76 m.

Comment: @Oded Ping! Ping!

Comment: This appear to be an OS X specific issue - having problems tracking down, in particular when one doesn't have access to such hardware.

Comment: @Oded Guess so. I can use my computer to help you fix this if you like

Comment: Talking to the right team internally helps... Got someone looking at this.

Comment: Repro in Safari(8.0.4) and Chrome. Style is added to the h1 as inline style (`margin-bottom: 15px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`). Yuk.

Comment: @Oded any updates, 2 weeks later? (yeah I know, not yet 6-8 weeks but trying my luck :))

Comment: @Oded Did you forget this ;-;

Comment: @Oded any updates, 6 months later?

Comment: Designed changed, no longer repro. Close?